# How to fix Divi blog posts to display the posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Divi Blog Posts Not Showing. When I click on the desktop view option of the Divi Builder it shows all the posts, but when I click to view the blog page it shows a blank page without any post and it displays some error in the console as I add in below, please help me how to solve the issue!

Errors:

```
Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
at et_core_page_resource_fallback (<anonymous>:1:153)
at HTMLLinkElement.onload (https://www.bitgivefoundation.org/blog/:234:489)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:74
at custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:74
at Object.<anonymous> (custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:74)
at Object.<anonymous> (custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:74)
at n (custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:2)
at Module.<anonymous> (custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:79)
at n (custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:2)
at custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:2
at custom.unified.js?ver=4.4.8&time=1592759351:2

Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
at S.fn.init.S.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (frontend-bundle.min.js?ver=1.0.0&time=1592759351:1)
at e (jquery.min.js:2)
at t (jquery.min.js:2)

e.indexOf is not a function
at S.fn.init.S.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (frontend-bundle.min.js?ver=2.2.5&time=1592759351:1)
at e (jquery.min.js:2)
at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: You might try checking after disabling all (other) plugins and any custom theme modifications. Looks like a potential caching error or "conflict."

Comment: I did, but it didn't fix.